# Can HTTP servers on a LAN be hacked into from the web?

Tags: networking, security, internet, http, microcontroller

I have set up a web server on a ESP8266 microcontroller inside my local area network. HTTP GET requests sent to this unit can switch on and off a mains outlet, and I'm planning on deploying a couple of those around the house.

This LAN is connected to the internet using a standard internet box (router+modem). I want to prevent anyone from outside the LAN, including anyone from internet, from sending anything to the microcontroller.

Let's assume people can't hack my WPA-PSK-protected Wifi, is my setup a concerning security breach? How difficult is it for anyone to hack into my DIY smart outlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it shouldn't be possible for anyone on the outside to access the server directly (as long as you don't forward any ports on the router), you'll be vulnerable to something like [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). For example, if someone sent you an email message in HTML format (or get you to load a web page, or...), with an inline image loaded from `http://192.168.1.50/control?outlet=all&action=off` (or whatever its IP address and syntax are), your mail client will try to load an image from that URL, and your outlets will turn off (or whatever).

So, if you have any sufficiently geeky friends who know your network setup, expect to get pranked. Actually, you should also expect random XSRF hits trying to exploit random other devices you may or may not actually have; if the controller's web server gets confused by any of these, they may break it accidentally.

[Update] Securing this better will depend a lot on what crypto capabilities the web server has -- I didn't see much info in a quick search, so I'm not sure what it can do. The simplest thing to do is add a password variable to the request. This isn't particularly secure, since it'll be visible on the wire, stored in history on the client and logged on the server, etc, but it's better than nothing (and better than using weird syntax, since it's easy to change). Do **not** use the same password you use for anything else.

Switching from GET to POST would also help a bit, especially since the HTTP standard says that GET requests aren't supposed to change the state of the server -- that is, it's supposed to be safe for clients to send/not sent GET requests depending on e.g. the state of their caches. Using HTTPS would help even more (if the server supports it). Using WebDAV digest authentication (instead of a password string) would also be good (again, if the server supports it), but you'd need to add some sort of protection against replay attacks for it to be really effective.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot! Is there a way to be protected against that, perhaps something to add to the web server's firmware? For example, if the syntax is not intuitive, they wouldn't be able to do that unless they sniff the requests on my network from inside?

Comment: @MisterMystère See update.

Answer (score 1):

Although anything is possible, if you don't have any ports mapped via port forwarding, sometimes called virtual server, especially 80, 443, and 8080, or whatever ports your webserver uses... The chances of an attack from outside the LAN getting through your router to that device are near zero.

But again, without a more thorough security review, don't take this as the final answer. If there is a will, there is a way no matter what precautions you take.

Comment: Thanks. Gordon Davisson seems to have found a loophole. What's your take on this?

Comment: Very plausible, however, for someone to do this they would need very specific knowledge of your internal network including the IP address and exact syntax used... Cross sight forgery? Possible, but in your residential situation probably as likely as being bitten by a shark. For these too work a person would to know a high level of detail about your internal network and the commands necessary.  This could be a minor concern if you have sufficiently knowledgeable friend(s) with a prankster side, but I probably wouldn't be to concerned. Worst case it's running your lights, not your bank account

Comment: True, although I'm concerned about people activating heater fans in my appartment when I'm away (also for the electric bill...). So there isn't a way for anyone outside my network to list all machines listening on the port 80 and brute force requests until they get a reply?

Comment: Again, to say their isn't a way would be a lie, but if port 80 is closed in the firewall, an outside user can't directly access it. The reality is there is always a way to hack anything, given sufficient time, resources, and some kind of want to do it... But the reality in your situation is the likelihood of it happening is miniscule, approaching zero.